# No value given for one or more required parameters with two OleDBCommands

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, oledbcommand

So I have two different blocks to update 2 different cells in my access database.  The First UPDATE works perfectly fine and does the update every time.  The Second block, however is giving me an error each time it reaches the ExecuteNonQuery() call.

"No value given for one or more required parameters"

Here's the code:

```
OleDbCommand cmdUpdateToolStatus = new OleDbCommand(@"UPDATE Tools SET ToolStatus= @Status WHERE ToolID= @tid", conn);
cmdUpdateToolStatus.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", 0);
cmdUpdateToolStatus.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tid", PBOXTOOLIDS[0]);
conn.Open();
cmdUpdateToolStatus.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();

OleDbCommand cmdUpdateEmpID = new OleDbCommand(@"UPDATE Tools SET EmployeeID= @eid WHERE ToolID= @tid", conn);
cmdUpdateEmpID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", EMPID);
cmdUpdateEmpID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tid", PBOXTOOLIDS[0]);
conn.Open();
cmdUpdateEmpID.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

I've even tried replacing EMPID and PBOXTOOLIDS[0] with actual numbers that should work, and the second section will just not get passed that error message.

I'm rather new to working with databases, especially in C#, but something is wrong with this code.

The database fields are expecting numbers, if that helps at all.

Is there a different way that I could update the db with the correct information?  I could use OleDbCommand for one and possibly some other way??  I'm in a panic right now lol

Answer (score 1):

No, there is nothing wrong with the original code you posted in your question. I copied and pasted your code blocks into a minimal C# console application and both UPDATEs work fine. The test app, in its entirety, is

```csharp
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace toolTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection())
            {
                conn.ConnectionString =
                        @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                        @"Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;";

                OleDbCommand cmdUpdateToolStatus = new OleDbCommand(@"UPDATE Tools SET ToolStatus= @Status WHERE ToolID= @tid", conn);
                cmdUpdateToolStatus.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", 7);
                cmdUpdateToolStatus.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tid", 1);
                conn.Open();
                cmdUpdateToolStatus.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();

                OleDbCommand cmdUpdateEmpID = new OleDbCommand(@"UPDATE Tools SET EmployeeID= @eid WHERE ToolID= @tid", conn);
                cmdUpdateEmpID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@eid", 2);
                cmdUpdateEmpID.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tid", 1);
                conn.Open();
                cmdUpdateEmpID.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

There must be something else going on in your code that is causing your second UPDATE to fail.

Comment: would it matter if it is a windows form application?  I don't see anything wrong on my side.  I'm checking the values in the array and both values are there and correct.  :/  This project is due in 2 weeks..